# Java Retrofit | Calling a method's return in a lambda expression

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Suppose I have this piece of code

```
public String userName(){
//Retrofit setup here 
MyAPI service = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);
 Call<Users> call = service.getUser();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Users> call, Response<Users> response) {
                  //suppose I get what I want here:
                  response.body().getUserName();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Users> call, Throwable throwable) {
                   //let's just say we return "User not found" onFailure
                }
            });
//return statement here
}
```

Is there a way I can have the String return statement of the userName() method in lambda expression? If not, what's the simplest way (with minimal amounts of processing) I can use to achieve this.

Retrofit has a `isExecuted` method for calls so I was thinking about using that in a while loop. But I just wanted to know if there's an easier way to do it before I proceed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. `enqueue` means: Do this asynchronously. As in, not now, later.

Where you wrote `return statement here`? That runs before the onResponse/onFailure methods do, so you can't 'move' the return statement there - your method must return (and therefore, know what to return) before the place where you want the return statement to be has even run, which makes that impossible.

This is the problem with asynchronous API: They suck to code against. This is what people are talking about when you say 'callback hell': You need to redesign all your code so that this method needs to return nothing; instead, all code that would act upon the return value needs to be packed up in a lambda and shipped to this method, so that you can invoke that lambda (and pass the thing you want to return, such as `"User not found"`, as parameter instead).

There are probably ways to not use enqueue here, I'd look at that first.

Comment: I can't really redesign the code here because I'm working with an AWS library and I had just provided a minimal reproducible example. But I get the idea. But yeah, thanks for the help. Let me look at ways that don't use enqueues. Thank you

Comment: Oh. `Call` has `execute()` as well which does the job synchronously. Just had to change it up there